# Jasmine test with different matches in json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

i want to implement jasmine test with the next code:

This is my filter-service.js

```
 function FilterService() { 
 }

 FilterService.prototype.filter = function (companies, filter) {
   return companies;
 };
```

And my  filter-service-spec.js is

```
    describe("Filter service filter(...) tests", function() {
var filterService = new FilterService();
var allTestCompanies= [
    { id: 1, name: "company1 Test", admin: "Test Admin" },
    { id: 2, name: "company2", admin: "Test Admin", country: 'London' },
    { id: 3, name: "company3", admin: "Mery Phill" }      
];        

it('returns original collection if called with undefined filter', function() {
    var input = [1, 2, 3];

    var result = filterService.filter(input, undefined);

    expect(result).toEqual(input);
});
it('returns original collection if called with empty filter', function () {
    var input = [2, 6, 7];

    var result = filterService.filter(input, '');

    expect(result).toEqual(input);
});

it('only includes matching companies once', function() {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, 'Test');

    expect(result.length).toEqual(2);
});

it('matches exact text on company name', function() {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, "company1 Test");

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[0]);
});
it('matches exact text contained in company name', function () {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, "Test");

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[0]);
});
it('matches case invarient text contained in company name', function () {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, "test");

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[0]);
});

it('matches exact text of admin', function() {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, 'Mery Phill');

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[2]);
});
it('matches exact text in admin', function () {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, 'Phil');

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[2]);
});
it('matches case invarient text in admin', function () {
    var result = filterService.filter(allTestCompanies, 'PHIl');

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(allTestCompanies[2]);
});   
});
```

How i can implement a function in filter-service.js for pass the javascript tests. For now only pass the 2 first.

Comment: Your code doesnt do anything other than return the first argument passed in. so if you're testing the result against the first parameter of course they pass. Youve not told us what you're trying to do and it just likes you want someone to write code for you

Comment: Do you ask somebody write the code for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is actually very easy to do, but I will provide just with approach you should take. So lets begin ...

1. I hope you have an environment where you able to run your tests (Jasmine installed and you able to run your tests against "FilterService" object and "filter" method in particular). You said two first methods are succeeded.
2. Each Jasmine "it" function has description, for example "matches exact text on company name" (test #4). This is most important part you will be dealing with. We will talk about this test. Ask yourself what this description tells you? This means if you pass into "filter" method exact name of the company, the function should go through array of given companies objects and try to find match for exact company name.
3. Next you would need to look at implementation of Jasmine "expect" function. You will notice that returned result from the "filter" function call must be equal to the first element of the given array of companies because the name of the company in the filter parameter match to this object's "name".
4. After you implement this part and test succeeded, you would go to next test and add/change existing implementation to accomplish next "it" description.

This is called TDD (test driven development). Please read a bit on it before you start working.

Finally lets try to implement this test #4. Please note the code provided may not work, but as we agreed you will make it work, I just show the approach ...

```
function FilterService() { 
}

FilterService.prototype.filter = function (companies, filter) {
 // this is our result variable which we will return at the end
 var result;
 // for test #1 the "filter" parameter is undefined and the test description says "returns original collection if called with undefined filter" (#2 will look similar to test #1, add this by yourself)
 if (typeof filter === "undefined") {
    result = companies;
 }
 // jump to test #4 we are talking about. "it" says "matches exact text on company name"
 companies.forEach( function (companyObj) {
   if (companyObj.name === filter) {
     result = [companyObj];
     return false;
   }
 });
 // continue to modify the function to meet all criteria of every "it" description

 // we return our result
 return result;
};
```